# how to use LuxiMono with ShareLatex?

Tags: fonts, sharelatex

I would like to install `getnonfreefonts` to use LuxiMono with ShareLaTeX. 
I have seen instruction for installation for XeTeX.
Is it possible at all yo use LuxiMono and other fonts from `getnonfreefonts` on ShareLaTeX?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: 'no'. Longer answer: As you are using a shared/managed (La)TeX installation you can only use the font files that are included as part of the set up. You can't run the script `getnonfreefonts` on the server so you cannot use those fonts.